# SQL Server Sync Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-synchronization

Two quick questions:
1) I'm synchronizing two tables across two servers using the Synchronization Framework, but I do not need to synchronize all the columns. 
I can pass the columns I want in a collection:

```
DbSyncTableDescription tableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("tblSalesTracker", columnNames, serverConn);
```

Which works fine, but if any columns out side of my collection are modified in the table, a re-sync is triggered. I got around this by modifying the existing trigger the sync frame work creates on the source table, and checking for the columns I want.

So

- is there a way to create the update or set the trigger manually while settings/starting the provisioning process in c#? Instead of dropping/recreating later.

or

- a better way of doing this?

Question 2) Is there a way to synchronize to a table of a different name.

All of my code is based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928494.aspx).

Only difference is, it is SQL 2008 Express to SQL 2008 Express.

Comment: Answer to Q2 is here if anyone is looking: http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/08/